# How to optimize my css/html webpage?

Tags: html, css, http, web

I am working on a (html/css) website to improve my skills but I am not sure if I am doing it the right way, because I have a lot of floats and sizes. I also need help with some css things:

What I have:

[image: i.imgur.com/r3VGbWy.png]

What I need:
[image]

The red dimensions in the image are the dimensions I've tried to give the objects and which I am not sure if it is the correct way of doing it.
The black words are the things I would like to change, but I am not sure how I can do it in a good way.

All my code:
index.html:
http://pastebin.com/PZZY7bFA

style.css:
http://pastebin.com/HyEdM6qF

reset.css:
http://pastebin.com/gxqWzFHN

I did not post the css code of the navigation menu because it is already working in a correct way.

I would be very happy if anyone can help me.

Regards,

Engin

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't have that much time right now. But I tell you this:
Your logo is an  object wich is an inline element, same as  (link) and normal text.
To vertical center inline elements use `line-height: ?px;` in your css. Set the ? to the height of your header

To vertical center other elements, such as block elements (f.e. div) you can define the parent as a table cell `display: table-cell;` and assign `vertical-align: middle;` to your block element. Of course this would also work for inline elements but the first method is easier here, since you don't have to declare the parent as a table-cell.

Anyway, if you really want to design websites you have to get to know all the princeples and behaviors. Check the urls that were just posted and keep learning A LOT!

I hope you can finish the navigation now:)